# why are there typescript errors I only see in "ng build --prod" but not in "ng build" or "ng serve"?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, ng-build

In my Angular 11 application, `ng serve` and `ng build` don't report any error. But with `npm run ng build -- --prod --output-hashing=all`, which happens on the build server, I suddenly see an error:

```
Error: src/app/administration/clients/licensing-client.ts:7:15 - error TS6133: 'tap' is declared but its value is never read.

7 import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
                ~~~
```

My question is, why is this error not reported already when I do `ng serve`? Are those different configurations somehow?

Comment: `--prod` does a full production build, which enables additional checkins and validations. `serve` and build without production just do some controls and may emit javascript for invalid typescript anyway, with runtme errors to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share your `angular.json`, and `tsconfig.json`?

The `tsconfig.json` compiler option that produces this error is

```
"compilerOptions": {
...
   "noUnusedLocals": true,
...
}
```

Regarding why it heppens in the production mode, and not development:

It may be the AOT compiler and buildOptimization, especially if it is on for the production mode, and off for the development mode. Try turning on AOT for all modes, but disable buildOptimization for the development mode. Otherwise you will have production mode turned on while developing.